# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. - Going round in circles

Tags: magento2

**Magento CLI 2.3.3**

**I get the above error when visiting my homepage, checking the exception log i see this**

> main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not
>   exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist at
>   /home/admin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"}
>   []

**After looking for answers I found this which I run**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
```

**But now my homepage says**

Please upgrade your database: Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:

> Temando_Shipping data: current version - 1.5.0, required version -
>   1.6.0
>
> Vertex_Tax data: current version - 100.3.0, required version - 100.4.0
>
> Yotpo_Yotpo data: current version - none, required version - 3.0.0

**So I run**

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**and terminal says**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'origin.address.countryCode' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `temando_product_attribute_mapping` (`node_path_id`,`label`,`description`,`mapping_attribute_id`,`is_default`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**and my homepage is blank.**

If anyone can help me going round in circles with this I would much appreciate it. Thanks

**After trying the first 2 answers I check the error report again**

```
{"0":"Please upgrade your database: Run \"bin\/magento setup:upgrade\" from the Magento root directory.\nThe following modules are outdated:\nTemando_Shipping data: current version - none, required version - 1.6.0\nVertex_Tax data: current version - none, required version - 100.4.0\nYotpo_Yotpo data: current version - none, required version - 3.0.0","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#2 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:137]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Comment: truncate `setup_modules` table from database and try again `setup:upgrade` again

Comment: **no longer had that error but says this at the end**

Upgrading data... Duplicate Of Template Name

**everything still blank**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

**Temporary solution**:

- Login to Mysql database
- then update table `setup_module` of the `data_version` column same as `schema_version`

**OR**

1. Delete `var/cache` `generated`
2. Truncate `setup_module` in database
3. Run Following Commands in magento root Folder

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   chmod -R 777 var pub generated
   ```

Comment: **that brings me back to**

Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Temando_Shipping data: current version - none, required version - 1.6.0
Vertex_Tax data: current version - none, required version - 100.4.0
Yotpo_Yotpo data: current version - none, required version - 3.0.0

Comment: try `php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade`

Comment: thanks but no change, I have added the error log entry to the question

Comment: which version of magento you are using ?

Comment: Temporary solution: Login to Mysql database => then update table setup_module of the "data_version" column same as "schema_version

Comment: Magento CLI 2.3.3

Comment: Thank you Waqar Ali, that has worked as a temp solution. Really helps :)

Comment: i have updated my answer please mark as accepted so any one can get help